# ECONNREFUSED on redis what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, redis, capistrano, sidekiq

I have been working on this for days now, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Everything else is working, but I get the "ECONNREFUSED" on redis.
I have follow intances running:

```
app01 ROLE: app
web01 ROLE: web
db01 ROLE:db:primary
redis01 ROLE:redis_master
redis02 ROLE:redis_slave
sidekiq01 ROLE:redis
```

Here is the error from the productionlog:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)):
app/models/user.rb:63:in `send_password_reset'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

Everything is set-up by using the rubber-gem.

I have tried to remove all instaces and start from the start two times. Also I have tried to make a custom security-rule, but i'm not shure if I did it right.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Bringing this post back from the dead because I found it when I was struggling with the same problem today.  I resolved my problem by doing the following:

1. I added redis_slave or redis_master roles to the servers using `cap rubber:add_role`.  I found this will add both the specified role, and the generic "redis" role.  Assuming that you want redis01 to be the only redis_master after adding roles, I'd expect your environment to have:

   ```
   app01 ROLE: app
   web01 ROLE: web
   db01 ROLE:db:primary
   redis01 ROLE:redis_master
   redis01 ROLE:redis
   redis02 ROLE:redis_slave
   redis01 ROLE:redis
   sidekiq01 ROLE:redis_slave
   sidekiq01 ROLE:redis
   ```
2. After setting up roles, I updated the servers with `cap rubber:bootstrap`
3. In *my* environment, I'm deploying code from git, so I had to commit these changes and run `cap -s branch="branch_name_or_sha" deploy` to get rubber/deploy-redis.rb on the servers with the new roles and execute it.

After doing all this, redis runs on all my nodes without throwing `Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED))` error on any of them.

Good Luck!